# How nodes work in ElasticSearch Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster of 4 nodes.

**Node 1:**
  node.master: true
  node.data: true
**Node 2:**
  node.master: true
  node.data: true
**Node 3:**
  node.master: true
  node.data: true
**Node 4:**
  node.master: false
  node.data: false

and 
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2.

Now, as per my understanding, there will be single master elected for the cluster and the master decides where and how to store the incoming data.

Say suppose, **Node 2:** goes down and never comes back. The cluster will still be up and running as reelection takes place when  **Node 2:** goes down.

But what happens to the data which was stored in **Node 2:**. Can any one please explain me the flow here.

Answer (score 0):

If node 2 goes down and never come back means you lost the data forever, unless you have replica configured.

If you have one replica for each shard, then you will have extra copy of each shard in different node.

So when node 2 goes down, the node 2 data will server from replica server from node 2 or node 1.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info.Now i have a scenario at my work place. One of the master eligible nodes is down. Now with the remaining 3 nodes i want to form a cluster and continue working. But there is a probem with logstash here. It is not pushing the incoming data from filebeat 
to elasticsearch.

Comment: It gives below error,  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - retrying failed action with response code: 503 ({"type"=>"unavailable_shards_exception", "reason"=>"[logstash-2017.06.05][1] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[logstash-2017.06.05][1]] containing [3] requests]"})

Comment: May i know why this exception is shown in logstash logs. 

Once i clear the data folder in elasticsearch in all the 3 nodes, the exception was no more thrown in logstash.

So i am assuming here that the nodes in the new cluster had some pointers to the 4th cluster which is down and its not able to find it.
Once i cleared the data folder, all the references to the 4th node was deleted and this exception issue also got rectified.

Please let me know if my understanding is right here.

Comment: I want to understand why that exception occurred so that i can keep the root cause in mind to avoid such issues.

Comment: i think u have not configured replicas for logstash logs... if you do it will servet the data..!